# SD card Windows CE 6.0 for OMAP-L138

Tags: window, sd-card, bootable

I have a problem to create a bootable SD-Card. I created my own OS-WinCE-6.0 using Platform Builder of Visual Studio 2005, I got the nk.bin file, I copied and pasted in the SD-Card. I need it to run on the board "OMAP-L138 ". 
I tried to convert the .bin file to .nb0 file and do the same, I got the same problem.
unfortunately, when I turn on the board, nothing happen after, it doesn't start.
Please tell me what to do to solve this issue.

Thank you very much.
Youness

Answer (score 1):

Probably SD-Card needs Boot-loader binary (EBOOT.nb0) to Make a bootable SD-card.

You need to partition the SD-card,

Flash **NK.nb0** and **EBOOT.nb0** using **dd** command from Linux PC, or if TI is providing any utility (such as cfimager.exe by freescale), you can use that.